# how to insert data from one table to another table and in 2nd table matches the field

Tags: mysql

I have two tables purchases and item

```
Purchases(purchaseID purchaseDate, itemName,itemCost,itemQty)

Item(itemID,itemName,itemCost,itemQty).... itemID is auto Increment
```

now when I insert-data in purchases table I want it to aromatically insert in item table.

For example, for purchases values `(pur001,2014-04-09,caltex,2000,5)`
the item table will be `(1,caltex,2000,5)`

When I insert 2nd record in purchases table values `(pur002,2014-04-09,caltex,4000,10)`,
the item table should look like this `(1,caltex,6000,15)`

How can I do this?

Comment: How would mysql know what to automatically insert into the second table? This sounds like a scenario where you would put a trigger on the first table, and have it execute a stored procedure on insert

Comment: please give practical example about it

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you want to create some kind of statistical overview or "soled item counter" in the database. Is this right?
So the use case is: With every item sold, an entry in your Purchase table is updated.

From the relational database design point of view this does not make sense. It would be easier to create a query that selects all purchases, grouped by item id and sums up the item count per purchase. In this case, you don't have any "state" or calculated value in the DB. Normally such values are not wanted in a database.

Nethertheless. If you still want / need this, you can use SQL triggers that fire on INSERT and UPDATE (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html). These triggers get the inserted or updated values in. But with UPDATE the drama begins. What is your strategy, if the number of sold items are decreased? What happens if an order is canceled? You see, maybe it would be better to not hold such kind of data in the DB :)

Comment: i only want item table populated from purchases table if same item purchase again the item table qty attribute update accordingly

Comment: if i only populated item table from purchases using this query INSERT INTO item (itemName, itemCost, itemQty)
SELECT itemName, itemCost, itemQty
FROM  purchase
ORDER BY purchaseID DESC
LIMIT 1 then how can i calculate total item of each type

Comment: It still looks like the wrong approach. Or I miss something. Can you explain more detailed what you are trying to do? And please format your posts. They are currently hard to read :)

Answer (score 0):

Aromatically? As in giving off a pleasant scent when the insert happens?

One approach to achieving this is to create a TRIGGER that gets fired when an insert is performed on the purchases table.

But you also need to think in terms of an updates and deletes to the purchases table. What if a row is deleted from the purchases table. What if `itemQty` is changed, or if `itemName` is changed. Keeping the `item.itemQty` column "in sync" could require more than just activity than on insert.

Before we launch into CREATE TRIGGER syntax, you want to carefully consider what the intended goal is.

If the goal is to get a total of a particular item purchased:

```
SELECT p.itemName
     , SUM(p.itemQty) AS total_qty
  FROM purchases p
 WHERE p.itemName = 'caltex'
 GROUP BY p.itemName
```

An appropriate index

```
... ON purchases (itemName,itemQty)
```

would make for a very efficient query plan.

Adding the `"itemQty"`column to the `"item"` table effectively "breaks" Codd's rules for 3NF ("each and every attribute is dependent on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key". The `"itemQty"` attribute (column) of the `"item"` entity (table) is *NOT* dependent only on the key of the entity (`"item"`), ... it's dependent on the existence and attributes of other entities (rows in the `"purchases"` table).